# Tor automation for windows

Tags: windows

I remember a long time ago I saw a software that had some sort of an IDE that allows for tor browser automation via script.
It work for windows, and it wasn’t selenium
Anyone has any idea?
Many thanks
Michal erel

Comment: Anyone? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It was called Vidalia, sadly it was discontinued

Comment: Thank you for your answer! There was def another one I was using by another name. 
In any case - is it still possible to use the discontinued version somehow ?

Comment: almost no - the've changed enogh to make it incompatible, I've tried it some years ago - looks like a rewriting is required

Comment: Thank you for your response!  
Is there an automation platform available on other operating systems?

Comment: An automation of what kind you're speaking about? Vidalia-like or something else? There were some browser add-ons that were providing some similar functionality, but it's not good from the detection evasion point of view

Comment: I’m not familiar with Visalia but basically a system that couldn’t generate a search and automate a click to the search result corresponding to my website

Comment: What you're talking about is done via Selenium and it's completely unrelated to Tor - it's a different kind of automation. Use a separate VM routed through Tor an on that VM use regular Firefox to run a Selenium script backed by Selenium webdriver - that's how it will work safely.

Comment: Thank you I’ll try that!